# JSR-330 support in Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, jsr330

The SVN version of [Guice supports JSR-330 annotations](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/JSR330) ("JSR-330 Integration - This documents an experimental, unreleased feature available in Guice SVN only"). Google gives the advise: "For now, stick with Guice's annotations and Provider interface." Guice 2 is a year old now and I wonder if there will be JSR-330 support in the near future. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're comfortable using code from SVN, use that and the JSR-330 annotations. If you'd rather rely on a published release, use Guice's own annotations. Also, JSR-330 doesn't support optional injection.

Note that there's a tiny behaviour change with Guice post-2.0 to cope with the new `@Inject` annotation.

- In Guice 2.0 and earlier: Methods not-annotated with `@Inject` are injected, if they override a method that does have that annotation.
- After Guice 2.0: Guice not inject such methods. You need to reapply the annotation on every override.

We don't have a release date scheduled for Guice 2.1.

Comment: Guice 3.0 is now in late beta.

Comment: Update: Guice 3.0 is now released!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it is planned for 2.1 : http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/detail?id=424

Comment: Is there an up-to-date release plan for guice? (Guice 2.1 was announced for 2009 ...)

Comment: I don't know. Better ask someone from Guice concerning the release plan.

Answer (score 2):

FYI

Guice 3.0 discussions:
https://groups.google.com/group/google-guice-dev/browse_thread/thread/5a00dcc392fc8276?hl=en